# How many spectrogram frames per input character does text-to-speech (TTS) system Tacotron-2 generate?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, word-embedding, attention, text-classification, speech-synthesis

I've been reading on Tacotron-2, a text-to-speech system, that generates speech just-like humans (indistinguishable from humans) using the GitHub https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2.

I'm very confused about a simple aspect of text-to-speech even after reading [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05884.pdf) several times. Tacotron-2 generates spectrogram frames for a given input-text. During training, the dataset is a text sentence and its generated spectrogram (it seems at a rate of 12.5 ms per spectogram frame).

- If the input is provided as a character string, then how many spectogram frames does it predict for each character?
- How does training supply which frames form the expected output from the dataset? Because the training dataset is simply a thousand of frames for a sentences, how does it know which frames are ideal output for a given character?

This basic aspect seems just not mentioned clearly anywhere and I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.